# AngularJS - Get filter length in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

How can I access `filtered.length` from my directive `my-dir`?

```
<li my-dir ng-repeat="result in filtered = (results | filter:query | orderBy: 'title')">
    <h1>{{ result.title }}</h1>
    <p>Search hits: {{ filtered.length }}</p>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is you are trying to filter before establishing what you will be iterating through.

```
<li my-dir ng-repeat="result in SOME.resultset | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
    <h1>{{ result.title}}</h1>
  </li>
```

Also, query and title here need to be bound to an input element. Should look something like this:

```
  Search: <input ng-model="query">
  Sort by:
  <select ng-model="orderProp">
    <option value="title">Title</option>
    <option value="artist">Artist</option>
  </select>
```

To get length would look like this

```
Result Length: {{(resultset|filter:query).length}}
```

Comment: All the search logic behind works, I just want to access the length of the filtered results from my directive. I can access it in the markup, as you've done, but not in the directive.